# Adding interactive movie to Android application

Tags: android, dialog, android-animation

I'm building a new application to the Android platform and I need to add an interactive movie that would show to the user, how to use the application.

I want something like the video in Angry Birds, with the button that spreads to the outside of the dialog.

Like this:

[image]

First I though that I need some kind of a animation video, so I checked [the Android video view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html), but I can't figure out how to use it, and if I actually need it?

Secondly is this window is a regular dialog or something else?
I tried the regular dialog but I didn't came with the idea of this button, all the buttons is inside the dialog itself and I can't show it like I wan't (e.g. Angry Birds dialog).

Any help will be great, Thanks.

**EDIT:**  This is the custom dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Test"
        android:textSize="50dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/videoView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angry birds doesn't use the the Android Ui elements. They use a custom framework to show their dialogs. Therefore you will need to customize your own dialog as well.

If you your application really needs a video to demonstrate its use, maybe you should reconsider your application functionallity. Maybe a simple application will do with a set of screenshots and annotations.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any link that demonstrates how can I customize my own dialog in the same way? I tried couple of customized dialogs and none of them worked like I want.